# wcf nettcp оптимизация

Tags: оптимизация, wcf

.NET 4.6 , используется nettcpbinding, так понимаю в этом случае бинарная сериализация работает по умолчанию. Что можно настроить для оптимизации передачи данных , планируется подгружать на клиент до 1 000 000 записей примерно по 300-600 байт каждая, т.е. общий траффик может составить до 600 Мб хостинг IIS7.
Влияют ли как в случае передачи текста XML например названия полей ? как можно уменьшить объем ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для net.tcp binding по умолчанию используется Microsoft XML binary encoding. Это тот же XML по сути своей, только имена тегов не повторяются строками, а записаны один раз, а дальше только их индексы. Ну и еще несколько оптимизаций. Но по сути все равно XML.

Из встроенного в WCF можно попробовать streaming mode - чтобы WCF не держал все эти 1000000 записей в памяти перед отправкой (а в некоторых случаях и после). Но в этом случае будут ограничения на то что можно использовать: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

А клиенту нужен весь этот миллион записей одновременно? В нашем проекте мы в таких случаях либо возвращаем миллион "заголовков" (т.е. очень краткой информации об объекте), либо возвращаем первую порцию и общее количество (а иногда и без него). А дальше клиент запрашивает следующие "страницы" (по мере прокрутки списка пользователем, например).

Comment: Да клиенту удобно их получить сразу и работать с быстрым поиском для фильтрации, технически локально поиск по 1 млн. элементов работает шустро, остается оптимизировать передачу этих данных с сервера. Можно конечно фильтровать на сервере, но все равно сетевые лаги иногда могут тормозить. Если с оптимизацией трафика чтобы ужаться раз в 10 не выйдет, то придется использовать фильтр на сервере, данные скорее всего будут все в кеше на сервере и синхронизироваться с СУБД.